# Corona: Audio does not begin playing again after scene is re-created

Tags: audio, lua, coronasdk, scene

I am trying to play background sound, only during one scene. When this scene is destroyed, the sound should fade out and then stop. Then when the scene is re-created, the sound should start playing again.

Here is what I am trying:

```
local backgroundMusic
local backgroundMusicChannel

local function stopSound(event)
    audio.stop(event.channel)
    audio.dispose(event.handle)
    backgroundMusic = nil
end

function scene:create(event)
    backgroundMusic = audio.loadSound("music/intro.mp3")
    backgroundMusicChannel = audio.play(backgroundMusic, {loops = -1, fadein = 3000, onComplete = stopSound})
end

function scene:destroy(event)
    audio.fadeOut({channel = backgroundMusicChannel, time=2000})
end
```

The sound plays when the scene is created initially, and fades out correctly, but does not start again when the scene is created again.

When I change the destroy function to:

```
function scene:destroy(event)
    audio.fadeOut({channel = backgroundMusicChannel, time=2000})
    audio.stop(backgroundMusicChannel)
end
```

the sound does not fade out, because it stops immediately, but it DOES start again correctly the next time the scene is created.

I have also tried using audio.stopWithDelay, which fades out correctly, but similarly, does not begin playing again when the scene is created once more.

If anyone has any insights on what's going on here please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be you cannot (re)play the sound if it isn't stopped yet?
You also never dispose of the audio when the scene ends.
Inside create, stop the previous audio if it already exists.

You're better off creating the sound once and reusing it when needed.
If you use loadStream, you'll have to use audio.rewind() after playing it.

The documentation on this also states that you should probably use loadStream:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/audioSystem/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am stopping the audio and disposing of it. That's what's happening in the "stopSound" function - it's being called in the onComplete of the audio channel. I've verified that this function is being called. I had also tried using loadStream with no different results.

Comment: Does the function get called before or after the new scene loads?

Comment: After, since it's at the end of the fadeOut.

Comment: I assumed so. I thought that the problem was that the previous audio wasn't stopped yet.

Comment: I double checked that the audio is in fact getting stopped before the scene is re-created, and it is, so that's not the issue. But just in case I tried your suggestion: I am pausing the audio in the onComplete method instead, and rewinding, resuming, and fading in in the create method. The audio still does not start playing a second time. :(

Comment: did you destroy your scene after you went to second screen.because if you loaded the scene,after destroy only scene:create function will call.check second time the scene:create is called.